# RadioButton value duplicate with each other from different activities

Tags: java, android

I have this function that call RadioButton value from the Group.java to the Add.java. I use the same function on another activity called Status.java. Now, every time I click from either Group.java or Status.java, the result become duplicate. And every time I click the RadioButton, my EditText will dissappear.

Group.java

```
 RadioGroup radiog1;
RadioButton radio1, radio2, radio3, radio4, radio5;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_group);
    radiog1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiog1);
    radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    radio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    radio3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    radio4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio4);
    radio5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio5);
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .8), (int) (height * .6));


    radio1.setOnClickListener(this);
    radio2.setOnClickListener(this);
    radio3.setOnClickListener(this);
    radio4.setOnClickListener(this);
    radio5.setOnClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case (R.id.radio1):
            returnIntent.putExtra("GroupTag", "" + radio1.getText());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
            break;
        case (R.id.radio2):
            returnIntent.putExtra("GroupTag","" + radio2.getText());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
            break;
        case (R.id.radio3):
            returnIntent.putExtra("GroupTag", "" + radio3.getText());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
            break;
        case (R.id.radio4):
            returnIntent.putExtra("GroupTag", "" + radio4.getText());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
            break;
        case (R.id.radio5):

            returnIntent.putExtra("GroupTag","" + radio5.getText());
            setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            finish();
            break;


    }
}}
```

Status.java

```
    RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_status);
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .8), (int) (height * .6));

    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb3);
    rb4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb4);

    rb1.setOnClickListener(this);
    rb2.setOnClickListener(this);
    rb3.setOnClickListener(this);
    rb4.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case (R.id.rb1):
            returnIntent.putExtra("StatusTag", "" + rb1.getText());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
            break;
        case (R.id.rb2):
            returnIntent.putExtra("StatusTag","" + rb2.getText());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
            break;
        case (R.id.rb3):
            returnIntent.putExtra("StatusTag", "" + rb3.getText());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
            break;
        case (R.id.rb4):
            returnIntent.putExtra("StatusTag","" + rb4.getText());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
            break;



    }

}}
```

Add.java

```
 ImageButton ibtn, ibtn2, ibtn3, ibtn4,ibtn5;
TextView tvgroup;
TextView tvstatus;
int groupRequestCode;
int statusRequestCode;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

    tvgroup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvgroup);
    tvstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvstatus);

    ibtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtn);
    ibtn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtn2);
    ibtn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtn3);
    ibtn4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtn4);
    ibtn5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtn5);


    ibtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibtn5.setOnClickListener(this);



}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case (R.id.ibtn):
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, Group.class),  groupRequestCode);
            break;
        case (R.id.ibtn2):
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Due_Date.class));
            break;
        case (R.id.ibtn3):
            startActivity(new Intent(this,DueTime.class));
            break;
        case (R.id.ibtn4):
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, Status.class), statusRequestCode);
            break;
        case (R.id.ibtn5):
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Assignees.class));
            break;


    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == groupRequestCode) { // here you come back from Group.java
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            // do your stuff here
            String textViewName = data.getStringExtra("GroupTag");
            tvgroup.setText(textViewName);
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == statusRequestCode) { // here you come back from Status.java
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            // do your stuff here
            String status = data.getStringExtra("StatusTag");
            tvstatus.setText(status);
        }
    }
}}
```

The result :

[image]

Any kind of help would really be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I have this function that call RadioButton value from the Group.java to the Add.java*"? And where is this function?

Comment: @Rami what I meant is that using the onClick, I return the RadioButton value from Group.java to Add.java. I'm sorry if I misunderstood, I'm not that great in java, but I believe that when a value is return, it is called a function.

Comment: With this code, you're not returning the value from Groupe.java to Add.java because you start another instance of Add.java and this is why you lost your old data. What you exactly want to do with those 3 activities? get the selected CheckBox from Group.java and Status.java?

Comment: @Rami yes, I want to get the selected RadioButton text from Group.java and Status.java to Add.java. I'm very new to android so I must say I'm a very poor programmer. Is there any possible way I can get the selected text to view to TextView? And also possibly not lose my old data at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) method to pass data between activities.

So you need to change your code like that:

- In **Add.java**

1) Remove this code:

```
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extra != null) {
        String textViewName = extra.getString("SomeTag");
        tvgroup.setText(textViewName);
    }

    Bundle extra2 = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extra2 != null) {
        String status = extra2.getString("SomeTag");
        tvstatus.setText(status);
    }
```

2)

- Change `startActivity(new Intent(this,Group.class));`

to `startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,Group.class), groupRequestCode);`

- Also `startActivity(new Intent(this,Status.class));`

to `startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,Status.class), statusRequestCode);`

PS: `groupRequestCode` should be different from `statusRequestCode` ( for example 1 and 2).

3) Overrid onAcitivtyResult() method:

```
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
           if (requestCode == groupRequestCode) { // here you come back from Group.java
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    // do your stuff here
                    String textViewName = data.getStringExtra("GroupTag");
                    tvgroup.setText(textViewName);
                }
            }

           if (requestCode == statusRequestCode) { // here you come back from Status.java
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    // do your stuff here
                    String status = data.getStringExtra("StatusTag");
                    tvstatus.setText(status);
                }
            }
        }
```

PS: you can use `switch` instead of `if` blocs if you have many requestcode.

- In **Group.java**

Change

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Group.this, Add.class);
intent.putExtra("SomeTag", "" + radio1.getText());
startActivity(intent);
```

to

```
Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
returnIntent.putExtra("GroupTag","" + radio1.getText());
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

=> Do the same thing for the rest of the RadioButtons

- In **Status.java**

Change

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(Status.this, Add.class);
intent2.putExtra("SomeTag", "" + rb2.getText());
startActivity(intent2);
```

to

```
Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
returnIntent.putExtra("StatusTag","" + rb2.getText());
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

=> Do the same thing for the rest of the RadioButtons

Comment: thanks for the guide. However, when I click the RadioButton in Group.java, the TextView for Status.java also show the same thing. And now, the RadioButton in Status.java doesn't seem to do anything at all. BTW, the groupRequestCode and statusDeclare code need to be declare as int right?

Comment: Yes they should be declared as int. You want *tvstatus* and *tvgroup* to show the same thing? the call back result ?

Comment: No, no. The problem I have right now and before is that _tvstatus_ and _tvgroup_ show the same thing when I click the RadioButton. What I'm trying to do is that _tvstatus_ show the RadioButton text in Status.java, and _tvgroup_ to show Group.java RadioButton text respectively. Currently I can't achieve that. Sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Did you change your code like i suggest? it should do exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I did, sadly enough, it's like I said, the _tvstatus_ just copied the same text as _tvgroup_ as the Group.java RadioButton is click. When I click Status.java RadioButton, nothing happen.

Comment: Did you remove the code like i mentionned in "1)" ? and change the code for rest of the checkboxs?

Comment: Yes I did, I follow every guides you give, and the results still gave out the duplicate Views.

Comment: Thats strange it should work, i've changed the Tags name ("SomeTag")... make a try.

Comment: It still duplicate. Is it because I placed 'returnIntent.putExtra("GroupTag", "" + radio1.getText());'  inside the onClick method in Group.java? @Rami

Comment: There, I even change the 'SomeTag' with the new ones like you suggest

Comment: I think you forget to init groupRequestCode and statusRequestCode

Comment: I did, at the top. I've post the updated code above, I wonder what went  wrong.. Now when I click the radio in Group.java, the TextView of Status.java went missing, and vice versa when I click on radio in Status.java.

Comment: You just declared init groupRequestCode and statusRequestCode but you haven't init them. Assign some value to each one ( eg: groupRequestCode  =1; and statusRequestCode = 2; ).

Comment: Finally! That did the trick, I'm sorry mate for taking your time, I'm just really poor at this. Thank you for for helping me.